# Always include set of packages when creating a new conda environment

Tags: python, conda

Everytime I create a new conda environment I need to:

1. Always include black pylint pytest packages in addition to the project's specific ones
2. Always create three subdirectories: data, tests and a third with the environment's name
3. (optionally) create a corresponding new GitHub repo

Is there a "conda" way of achieving 1

Is there some utility / script to achieve the latter two items?

Comment: Have you looked at the Conda [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file)? There seems to be a way of achieving this by creating an environment file.

Comment: Thanks Carl, of course went through the docs a few times and did not see a solution but will try harder :)

Comment: I see what you were talking about. You suggest creating all new environments from a general (not project specific) environment.yml file, then activate it and within the new project environment conda install all other project specific package together, right? This could work well to solve task 1) Thanks